# Is it good to pass an AsyncTask instance to a method in another class for publishing progress?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an AsyncTask which calls a method of another class(where all the computational logic resides) which performs some background operations. I want to show the status/progress of the operation. I know that we can call `publishProgress()` in `doInBackground()` to publish the progress on to the UI thread. But as the logic resides in another class I need to pass the instance of an AsyncTask to call `publishProgress()` from there.

Is it a proper way? Will it cause any **runtime issue** or **memory leak**?

If someone has been through this, please guide me to achieve this in a proper way.

Edit1 : In the AsyncTask I am calling a **SOAP** web service

Comment: @PiyushGupta : Will it cause memory leak? considering a scenario when orientation is changed.

Comment: @Rithe : I am already using that. It is a callback method. But to we need to call `publishProgress(someValue)` in `doInBackground()`to trigger it.

Comment: Maybe you should start with telling us why do you use AsyncTask over say an IntentService, and give us some piece of code to see if there is a memory leak candidate, because in general I think it is possible to not leak when using AsyncTask properly while doing what you intend to do. the answer lays on how you do it...

Comment: @OfekRon : I am downloading a file from a server. While the download is in progress I don't want user to interact with the UI, so I am displaying a `ProgressDialog` where I want to show the progress of the operation. I am not familiar with IntentService. If this can be achieved by IntentService, I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't good idea to use AsyncTask at all - it is obsolete. Use rxJava library instead

Comment: Why do you say that it is obsolete?

Comment: Beacause it (AsyncTask) can only do some work on background thread (you sould provide thread pool also) and processes results on main thread. In  rxJava you can create data on one thread, process it in another (usually Schedulers.io() and Schedulers() computation, but you can create custom scheduler from HandlerThread), then handle results in different thread. You can also merge results from few tasks together, etc. Retrofit2 support rxJava, so it is very convenient if you use REST API

Comment: I'm agree with you. In fact, I use Retrofit+RxJava in my projects, not AsyncTask. Retrofit+RxJava is a better solution, yes, but it is not a reason why AsyncTask is obsolete. Using this stack (Retrofit+RxJava) involves more dependencies to the project and in some cases could be better using AsyncTask for simplicity.

Comment: @bigdestroyer only he(Alex )is saying that AsyncTask is obsolete ... not Google

Comment: rxJava takes 200kbytes in your production apk is used almost everywhere nowadays - from Retrofit call adapter to processing ui events (rxBinding) and readings from sensors. It is much more flexible tool, than AsyncTask.

Comment: But this doesn't make Async obsoleted ... On the other hand RxJava is creating many unnecessary object which fx `Observable.defer(func0);` which is `new Observable<T>(RxJavaHooks.onCreate(new OnSubscribeDefer<T>(func0)));`.... and so on

Comment: you can only do job on one thread and post result ONLY on main thread with AsyncTask. With rxJava's .zip() operator you can wait for as many jobs as you want and process result on any thread (not only on main thread), etc.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand in your question, you have a method you call from doInBackground, If that method doesnt save anything outside that method scope (in member or static member or in a member of a static member etc.) than it is rational to say that the execution itself will not leak the AsyncTask and the context that is being referenced from it. But there is more to that, even if the above is the case, you still have so many ways that this AsyncTask would leak.

Comment: Is there any alternative?

Comment: IntentService in conjuction with EventBus

Comment: Can't EventBus be used with AsyncTask? If yes, what is the difference between the two approaches? Which is efficient and less prone to memory leaks?

Comment: there is no such thing as prone to memory leaks, if you dont know what you are doing you may always find a way to cause a leak.

Comment: It can but i realy think that in your use case you better use IntentService